# In which CRAN mirror is the quadprog package available?

Tags: r, predictive-modeling, statistics, forecasting, data-analysis

I was trying to find the accuracy of some predicted data and I came to know that I can use the forecast package to do this. When I installed it and gave library(forecast), it said it needs quadprog package to work with forecast package.

I searched it in many CRAN mirrors [US(CA), US(IN), IRAN, MALAYSIA] and in all these only quadprogXT is available and with this package the forecast package is still not working.

In which CRAN mirror is this quadprog package available?

Answer (score 1):

The `quadprog` package is available on all CRAN mirrors, but it requires the latest R version: R 3.6.0 (released on Apr 26, 2019), see also https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/quadprog/index.html

```
> quadprog: Functions to Solve Quadratic Programming Problems
> 
> This package contains routines and documentation for solving quadratic
> programming problems.
> Version:    1.5-6
> Depends:    R (≥ 3.6.0)
> Published:  2019-04-26
```